# data is fetched but the state is not updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm fetching data from an endpoint. But the state is not updated. it's always undefined.

For some reason this.props.users is undefined. Am I doing something wrong?

After componentDidMount() I trigger the action fetchUsers that send a request to the endpoint. The data is fetched successfully but at the end the state is not updated.

This is my Layout component

```
class Layout extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                {
                    this.props.users.map((user, key) => {
                        return <a className="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">User #{user.id}</a>
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        channels: state.users.data,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchUsers: () =>
            dispatch(user.fetchUsers()),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Layout);
```

This the action file

```
export const fetchUsers = () => {

    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        let headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" };
        return fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3030/api/users/", { headers, })
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status < 500) {
                    return res.json().then(data => {
                        return { status: res.status, data };
                    })
                } else {
                    console.log("Server Error!");
                    throw res;
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    dispatch({ type: 'USERS_FETCHED', data: res.data });
                    return res.data;
                }
            })

    }
}
```

And this is the reducer

```
const initialState = {
    users: []
};

export default function channels(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'USERS_FETCHED':
            return { ...state, users: action.data };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you importing `fetchUsers`? You really dont need a `mapDispatchToProps`, when you `connect` a component `dispatch` is already injected to the component. aka `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Layout)`.... and then in your `componentDidMount`... `this.props.dispatch(fetchUsers())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error comes from your call to the dispatcher in the `mapDispatchToProps`. Since you are exporting directly the function `fetchUsers`, you should not be calling `user.fetchUsers`.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchUsers: () =>
            dispatch(fetchUsers()),
    }
}
```